# Типизированные файлы. Как считать информацию из файла?

Tags: c++, файлы, struct

Здравствуйте, пожалуйста, помогите решить задание: Написать программу, содержащую сведения о сотрудниках института. Каждая структура содержит поля - фамилия сотрудника, оклад, стаж работы.Написать программу, которая должна вывести: список работников со стажем в указанном диапазоне; фамилия сотрудника с наибольшим окладом и наименьшим стажем. Величина Х вводится по запросу с клавиатуры.

Содержимое файла:

> Ivanov 600 2
>   Petrov 800 2
>   Popov 1400 6
>   Smirnov 1100 4
>   Kuznetsov 1000 4

Проблема в считывании информации из файла, как я понял, необходимо записать в различные массивы каждую фамилию, оклад и стаж через цикл. Но как это сделать? Ведь в первый элемент массива необходимо ввести слово (фамилию), то есть: `strcpy` не поможет, как и `strncpy`, так как разный размер слов. Тогда как?

Вот с чего я начал:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct worker {
    char lastName[50];
    int salary;
    int experience;
};

int main()
{
    const int n = 5, m = 500;
    char text[m], lastNames[m]; 
    int salary[m], experience[m];
    worker ppl[n];
    ifstream listOW("listOfWorkers");
    while (listOW.getline(text, m)) // Далее не пойму что делать.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была похожая задача, надо было ввести информацию о странах из файла (название страны и среднии температуры весной, летом, осенью и зимой). Код выглядел вот так:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct country
{
    char name[20];
    double tspr, tsum, taut, twin;
};
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    struct country a[20];
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    ifstream f("Text.txt");
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        f >> a[i].name >> a[i].tspr >> a[i].tsum >> a[i].taut >> a[i].twin;
        i++;
    }
    n = i;
    f.close();
cout << "Сведенья о странах" << '\n';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << setw(25) << a[i].name << setw(10) << a[i].tspr << setw(10) << a[i].tsum << setw(10) << a[i].taut << setw(10) << a[i].twin << '\n';
}
system("pause");
}
```

А содержание файла Text.txt

```
NorthKorea 15 20 15 0
SouthKorea 15 20 15 0
Uzbekistan 16 25 17 10
```

Не забудь, что файл нужно подключить в проекту (проект->добавить новый элемент->добавить файл типа .txt) и добавить в папку проекта или указать полный путь к нему. В общем, с этим сам разберёшься. Надеюсь помог.